# Can I Pass a variable ByRef to a timer event in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, timer, pass-by-reference

I want to set a variable's value for a certain amount of time.  i.e. myVar = 1 for 20 msec then back to 0.  I have this implemented using a timer but the only way I can do it is to have a separate timer for each variable.

I would like to have a single timer that I can pass a duration and a variable by reference or something similar.

Can I Pass a variable ByRef to a timer event in vb.net?  Or something that has similar functionality?

Comment: No, you can't alter the event handler's signature. You can probably write some code that can do it without using timers at all (using tasks, with `Delay` and `ContinueWith`), but why would you want such a thing in the first place? Also, I doubt you can get 20 ms accuracy.

Comment: 20 msec is just an example.  Extreme accuracy of the timing is not my objective here.

Comment: Using tasks is the best way as suggested by Zohar but if you have to use timer, you can declare the variable on the class level _if that's an option_ and then you easily use it inside the timer event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work. But I need to add a disclaimer that I have only tested it in a very simple way and haven't checked for memory leaks etc

Add this sub to your code ..

```
Public Sub SetVar(ByRef variable As Integer, value As Integer, msDuration As Integer)
    variable = value
    Thread.Sleep(msDuration)
    variable = 0
End Sub
```

Each time you want to set a variable to a value for a time period, insert this at the point where you want to change the value ..

```
Dim t As New Task(Sub()
                      SetVar(a, 100, 2000)
                  End Sub)
t.Start()
```

Comment: David I gave your answer a try and it did what I needed it to do.  @zohar I tried Task.Delay as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096(v=vs.110).aspx) and it worked as well however it stopped everything else on the form while it was executing which is not something I desire (I know I didn't mention that in my original question).  I am not familiar with Task.Delay, is there a way to use that without that side affect?

Comment: I'm not an expert on async programming. I *think* that `Task.Delay` should delay only a specific task. Anyway, if David's answer solved your problem you should use it (and mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.)